# how to get leaflet current zoom level in javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to get the current zoom of the leaflet map when I scroll the mouse or press the zoom buttons?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: my problem is solved with this code : `map.on('zoomend', function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.getZoom());
    });`

Answer (score 2):

As per [the documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-map-state-change-events), you could listen on the `zoom` event for "any change in zoom level, including zoom and fly animations" or the `zoomend` event for "when the map zoom changed, after any animations.". Then, use the [`getZoom()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getzoom) method on a `Map` instance to get "the current zoom level of the map view".

```js
const map = L.map('map', {
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    zoom: 13
});

L.tileLayer(
  'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  }
).addTo(map);

map.on('zoom', ({ target }) => {
  console.log(target.getZoom());
});

map.on('zoomend', ({ target }) => {
  console.log(target.getZoom());
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```